# iOS - Any way to get another app's now playing song info

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

5 years ago there was the same question where everybody answered 
"No, you can't, it's iOS sandbox", in general, then it was a iOS 5, 
but now is 2016 and iOS 9.3 is coming up and the same question: 
My app need to know information (tittle, artist, album) about now playing song in system, that means it need to support any player like built-in Apple Music or Spotify, Bandcamp and more. I tried to access by `MPMusicPlayerController.nowplayingitem`, but it works only with Apple Music app, I tried to call `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, and as I understand, it just let me set some info to Control Centre and lock screen if your app is nowPlaying in iOS, but if not, it returns `nil`.
 Is there any way to do this? *Swift answers welcome*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37198219/how-to-get-another-apps-currently-playing-audio